Non-perturbative properties of 2+1-dimensional $()$ Yang-Mills Theory
Is 2+1 $SU(N)$ YM theory confining? Does it have also non-trivial topological properties? What's the form of the beta function for 3-dim YM?

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9809087

Also see this.
